# How do I log in after typing Ctrl+Alt+F1?

Tags: login, login-screen

Could not login. I used (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd>) I got the message:

```
bdin3d-Satellite-C55-A login:
```

What do I type here?

Comment: That's `tty1`. You can run commands from it.

Answer (score 4):

Type your userid. Then, when prompted, type your password.

**NOTE**: The password will not show up as you type it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It worked. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you can rephrase "why this happened" as a reasonable question (see http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask), ask another Question. If I were to produce a wonderful answer for the second question, other users could not find it from your original question. So I won't.